# AWS s3 bucket shows 1 file less

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have used aws cli tool to move couple of folders named: 2014, 2015, 2016 etc from root directory:

```
/2015/
```

into:

```
/images/2015/
```

When I moved them it seems that there is one file less in each bucket:

Before copying:

[image: Screenshot from 2021-03-26 10-33-36]

After coping:

[image: Screenshot from 2021-03-26 10-33-47]

Could you help me to understand this phenomena ?

Comment: How did you copy them? Do you have cli command you used? Maybe you missed one file?

Comment: @Marcin Here is sample command:
aws s3 sync s3://path/to/bucket/2014 s3://path/to/bucket/2014/images --profile john@smith.com

Comment: Issue an `aws s3api head-object` against each of the 2014 keys such as `images/2014/`. Does the 2014 object exist in the source but not in the destination?

Comment: @jarmod For now yes, all objects exist in source and destination.

Comment: Did you issue a head-object against the folder key as requested? For both source and destination.

Answer (score 2):

The count is probably including/excluding the 'folder object'.

Normally, there is no need to create folders in Amazon S3. Simply putting an object in a particular path (eg `/images/2014` will "create" the `images` and `2014` folders -- they 'appear' to exist, but they actually do not exist. Deleting the objects will make the folders disappear.

However, it is possible to create a folder by clicking **Create folder**. This will create a **zero-length object with the same name as the folder**. This will force the folder to appear, even when there are no objects inside the folder.

Therefore, it is likely that the "off by 1" count of objects is related to a folder that was/wasn't created via the *Create folder* command. I have previously seen exactly this behaviour.